# PHP SoapVar request with attributes

Tags: php, soap-client

I need to create request with attributes like " barbaz"

I tried to do that via array

```
$arr = array(
  'Foo' => array(
     'attr'=>'bar',
     'Baz'=>array( '_' => 'barbaz', 'attr'=>'foobar')
  )
);
```

and via Class. But in both cases I got
barfoobar

What is wrong?